# firebase storage and database rules communication

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

i need to store certain variables in the database and in the storage. but is important to have the certainty that this variables will be saved in the two databases and not only in one, furthermore this variables must be have the same values. but i see that storage and database not are in communication.
how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that currently, security rules from one service can't access data from another service. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/groups$2C$20storage%7Csort:date/firebase-talk/77i9CRlwg88/5dSIVzXxGwAJ) for more info (similar general problem).

If the data you're hoping to share is user specific, you can mint custom tokens which contain this data, that can be shared across services (as both services get the same token).

Comment: the problem is that in my case the data must be modificable by other users. if it modificable only by is owner it would be less complicated. but in this case the synchronization of data is very important because without the sync other user could voluntarily create a data inconsistency.this solution is ok but require a nodejs server

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found out a solution?

Comment: Same problem. We need to be able to write rules for storage based on DB contents. Why we do not have this feature?