# Firebase Storage Security Rule : Check if another object exists / check object's metadata

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

In Firebase storage security rules (not realtime database), is there any way to perform a check if another object exists at path, or another object's metadata exists?

---

**Some background**

Currently my storage security rules are set up so that users only have read access, and not write access to their `/users/{userId}/` paths.

I have an admin cloud function that saves a file to `/users/{userId}/necessary-file.pdf`. And I don't want users to be able to modify or write this file and only cloud functions to have the right to do. To achieve this I think I can match for the filename like :

```
match /users/{userId}/{fileName} {
   allow write: if !fileName.matches("necessary-file.pdf")
}
```

---

**Question**

Is there any way for me to only allow users to write **some-other-file.pdf** if they already have a **necessary-file.pdf** at the same path (or even somewhere else if that works better). All while still disallowing them to write **necessary-file.pdf**.

So is there any way for me to do something like this pseudo-code? :

```
match /users/{userId}/{fileName} {
   allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
   allow write: if (!fileName.matches("necessary-file.pdf")) && ("necessary-file.pdf".exists())
}
```

As an alternative, I can have my cloud functions write a metadata to **necessary-file.pdf** and check for that too. is there any way I can perform something like this pseudo-code? :

```
allow write: if "necessary-file.pdf".metadata['canUserWrite'] == 'yesUserCan'
```

---

**Finally**

What's really cool about this is that, if this is in any way remotely possible, it can be used to communicate between firebase database and firebase storage rules in a not-so-realtime way. [(referring to this question here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214047/firebase-storage-and-database-rules-communication) A cloud function can listen for changes in the intended field in realtime database, and write a file to firebase storage, which firebase storage can check for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firebase's Cloud Storage security rules can only access information about the current request and file. They don't have access to the full storage system, so can't check whether another file is present.

The reason for this is that the rules are evaluated in memory for every request. Providing access to Cloud Storage for other objects would slow the performance down, making the system unscalable. That same reason explains why you can't access the Firebase Database from the security rules.

If you want some control like this, you'll want to look in Cloud Functions for Firebase. If you have your users upload their files into a "staging" area, you can have a Cloud Function validate whether they met all prerequisites and only then move the file into the actual location (making it available for further processing or for clients to see).

Comment: Makes perfect sense! I'll do some more thinking around this then. Thanks a lot for the quick reply and happy 4th of July Frank!

Answer (score 0):

### (Another Solution) Restricting Storage Access with Auth Claims

Cloud Storage Rules has access to auth info for the request user. By setting up a check during the authorization process an auth property can be added for later access validation in storage rules.

---

**Original Question:**

> Is there any way for me to only allow users to write
> some-other-file.pdf if they already have a necessary-file.pdf at the
> same path (or even somewhere else if that works better). All while
> still disallowing them to write necessary-file.pdf.

Yes, this could be done by checking an `auth.token`.

**Example flow for a Web App w/ Google Signin:**

1. Create a Cloud Function to set a custom claim that checks for the existence of that file against the current auth user.
2. Upon success of the user authorizing via Google call that cloud function for it to set a value to the auth object.
3. Check `auth.token` in the storage rule.

**Web Example for Custom Claims:**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims?hl=ro#examples_and_use_cases

**Example Storage Rule:**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions?hl=ro#group_private