# Cloud Storage for Firebase Security Rules: Allow Write If Folder Exist

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

The problem: I need unauthenticated user's to upload videos to Firebase storage, but I don't want to just open it up the world/public. I want to make the public know my videoID (which will act like a token) to upload files. The video id's will be unique key + random key so they can not be easily guessed.

In Cloud Storage for Firebase I have a folder for video Id 12345:

```
videos/id12345
```

Inside this folder I have one file:

```
    -placholder.txt
```

I want to allow users (authenticate and unauthenticated) to add video's to this folder. I.e.

```
videos/id12345/
    -placholder.txt
    -videoRecording.mp4
```

However, I only want them to add video's to 'videos/id12345' IF the placholder.txt file exist.

Rules would look something like this:

```
 service firebase.storage {
   match /b/{bucket}/o {
     match /videos/{videoId}/{fileName}{
       allow read :if  resource.parent().exist();
       allow write: if resource.parent().exist() ;
     }
   }
 }
```

Can I do this with Firebase Storage Security rules?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is possible. There's definitely no way to check if the folder exists, since folders don't really exist to begin with (they're just a naming convention from Firebase on top of Cloud Storage). But (afaik) you can't even check if `placholder.txt` exists, since there's no way to check for other files. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910393/firebase-storage-security-rule-check-if-another-object-exists-check-objects

Comment: Thanks Frank. Do you think creating a signedUrl would work? https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.5.x/File#getSignedUrl

Comment: Work for what? I'm not sure what signed URLs have to do with checking for existence in security rules, but I may be missing something there. Please explain.

Comment: Sorry, should have explained better. I meant will a signedUrl work for my original problem, "I need unauthenticated user's to upload videos to Firebase storage, but I don't want to just open it up the world/public" ... It looks like it will solve the issue. I'm going to test using signedUrls, and will follow up here

Comment: It worked! Even if Firebase storage security rules are "write" = false, then you can upload files using a gcp signedUrl. This is an amazing feature, but did require a little setup seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768136/cors-on-firebase-storage/47779318#47779318

Comment: Ah. The Cloud SDKs bypass Firebase security rules. They'remeant to be used only in a trusted environment, e.g. your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

Comment: Security rules only really apply when accessing files from the Firebase client SDKs.  When you use Cloud tools (such as signed URLs, and the server SDKs), it bypasses Firebase security rules and uses Cloud ACLs on the files instead.