# Firebase storage rules: authenticate the allowed user

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have a channel for communication between two users and I use Firebase storage to transfer files between these users.
I don't want a third user to have access to the channel's files.

I'm trying to identify authorized users using 'authfile' and the metadata inside it.
That authfile is uploaded using admin sdk.

Only specific users can download and upload files to specific path in storage where the authfiles metadata contains his uid. still the users are not allowed to touch the authfile.

The metadata inside the authfile looks like this:

```
metadata: {
  AvnYaUFdaJh1j0FMIiKWoIC2MDw1: true, // firebase userId 1
  YhFyYRbutlf1PFI4NLKTN4qWRhQ2: true, // firebase userId 2
}
```

[my storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coOZT.png)

The rules I've tried:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {

  // Channel Media    
  match /media/{channelId}/{allPaths=**} {
    
    function isAllowedUser(uid) {
      return /authfile.resource.metadata.users[uid] == true;
    }

    allow delete: if isAllowedUser(request.auth.uid)
      && request.resource.contentType != 'authfile'

    allow read: if isAllowedUser(request.auth.uid)
      && request.resource.contentType != 'authfile'
    
    allow write: if isAllowedUser(request.auth.uid)
      && request.resource.contentType != 'authfile'
      && request.resource.size < 16 * 1024 * 1024;
      
    }
  }
}
```

I am writing Firebase storage rules for the first time and would like advice on how this could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need 'users' here.

```
function isAllowedUser(uid) {
    return /authfile.resource.metadata.users[uid] == true;
}
```

This should be valid
`resource.metadata[uid] == true;`

Additionally, if you need something like checking existence of another file or it's metadata, consider using Cloud functions as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911454/13130697).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I'm trying to make this app to work just cheap so fewer Functions requests are better.
Maybe i just add
some channel secret to the metadata of the file sent by the user, which I share with the parties to the conversation when the channel is created.
I think this could be safe enough. However, the files sent to the storage will be e2e encrypted.